# How do I make a 3rd party app for Pokemon go?

Tags: android, iphone

So basically I want to make a 3rd party app but not sure where to start, can anyone lend some guidance? I don't need help on the coding side just where to find the resources of possible.

Comment: Please try this http://stackoverflow.com/tour before ask.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this post, [Niantic, Inc.](https://www.nianticlabs.com/), the developers of Pokémon GO, have made no indication that they plan to release an SDK or extend any APIs as it relates to their game.

There is however a group of like-minded developers that are trying to put something together here [r/pokemongodev](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongodev)

Hope this helps, good luck!